# Issue navigating to xml element with same name, changing different attribute

Tags: python, xml

If have an xml file that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<apple view_filter="simple" version="1" format="1">
 <apples fruit_id="3" type="red" name="american">
  <basket version="1" type="6" pieces="12" expiration="12">
  <fruit_type colour="000" fruit_type="0x" weight="32">
  </basket>
 </apples>
</apple>
```

For the element **fruit_type="0x"**, I want to be able to use python code to navigate to that element and change the text (0x) of it's attribute. I also want to do the same for 'colour' and 'weight'.

How can I do this because when I try to navigate to fruit_type, I end up changing the fruit_type (first element) not the one that is fruit_type = '0x'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that does exactly what I want is:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


 parent = ET.parse("d:\\untitled\\note.xml")
 root = parent.getroot()

 for nodes in root.getchildren() :
  for subNodes in nodes.getchildren() :
    for mynode in subNodes.iterfind('basket'):
        print("##### Before Change of attributes ########### \n")
        print(ET.tostring(mynode))
        print("\n ##### After Change of attributes ###########\n")
        mynode.set('fruit_type', '0234')
        mynode.set('colour', '999')
        mynode.set('weight', '45')
        print(ET.tostring(mynode))
```

Comment: Just used the iterfind method you suggested.  Worked great! I had the same named attributes in my xml file and the regular find method was only finding the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code how you can change the attributes of Fruit_type:

**Sample Code**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


parent = ET.parse("d:\\untitled\\note.xml")
root = parent.getroot()

for nodes in root.getchildren() :
    for subNodes in nodes.getchildren() :
        for mynode in subNodes.getchildren():
            print("##### Before Change of attributes ########### \n")
            print(ET.tostring(mynode))
            print("\n ##### After Change of attributes ###########\n")
            mynode.set('fruit_type', '0234')
            mynode.set('colour', '999')
            mynode.set('weight', '45')
            print(ET.tostring(mynode))
```

**Output**

```
##### Before Change of attributes ########### 

b'<fruit_type colour="000" fruit_type="0x" weight="32">\n            </fruit_type>\n        '

 ##### After Change of attributes ###########

b'<fruit_type colour="999" fruit_type="0234" weight="45">\n            </fruit_type>\n        '
```

hope this helps

Comment: Hi, actually I'm reading in from an xml file and your code is giving me error..I assume it's the ET.fromstring function? How do I use this code with an xml file not string?

Comment: Hi, it's changing the values of the desired elements however, it's also actually creating the 3 elements that were modified in every other child following the <basket> xml line as the document actually has more childen after 'basket'. Hope you can understand the problem.

Comment: update: I have fixed the issue with using the command:  for mynode in subNodes.iterfind('basket')

Comment: i can understand it was always changing attribs of a fixed tag